# Ionic 2 login google firebase error 10: Unable to parse id_token

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, authentication, google-plus

I have to login with google plus and firebase. I use the next code to get the login:

```
loginGoogle() {
    this.googlePlus.login({})
        .then((response) => {
            const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(response.accessToken);
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(response))
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error: ", error)
        });
}
```

But always returns next error:

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid",
            "message": "Unable to parse Google id_token: ya29.GltpBZ_0uSz2G...."
        }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unable to parse Google id_token: yya29.GltpBZ_0uSz2G...."
}
```

I check the SHA1 and put in the firebase project android and create a google's project, but nothing fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the webClientId options property to the googlePlus login method

As mentioned in google plus cordova docs you will need the Web-client Oauth 2.0 id here you can find this in your firebase console authentication-> signIn method -> click edit on google sign-in method there under web sdk you will find the web client id use that id in your googleplus login webClientId property.

if you want a new one you can create one like this:

You have to create Web-client Oauth 2.0 id here https://console.developers.google.com . After that you will have client id and secret
Open https://console.firebase.google.com and goto Authentication -> Google -> Settings -> Web SDK and use clien od and secret you have got on the step 1.

```
this.googlePlus.login({
  'webClientId': 'client id of the web app/server side', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I add the "webClientId" and I can to login.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I am using this plugin https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/tree/main and i had the same problem while using

```
  signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithGoogle();

    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      result.credential?.accessToken,
    );

    const auth = getAuth();
    await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
  };
```

I had to change the `result.credential?.accessToken` to `result.credential?.idToken`